# Osmosis leaving out relations

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

I'm trying to extract administrative relations from a country extract of Ukraine (downloaded from http://download.gisgraphy.com/openstreetmap/pbf/UA.tar.bz2). Ultimately I'm wanting to get the OSM administrative relations converted to GeoJSON.

I'm using Osmosis to parse the PBF and write to a new PBF with just the administrative relations. When I run Osmosis as below, I seem to losing some shapes. In the case of Ukraine I'm losing the relation for the country (OSM ID 60199):

`$ osmosis --read-pbf file=UA.pbf --tf accept-relations "boundary=administrative" --used-way --used-node --write-pbf UA_administrative.pbf`

Any idea why this leave out some shapes? Oddly enough, if I use Osmosis to insert directly into a PostGIS database with `--write-pgsql`, the relation for Ukraine is there.

Comment: no direct solution by me, but what about filtering with https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter instead of osmosis?